# Syntax error in Cursor and dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, syntax, cursor, dynamic-sql

My following code gives error:  (SQL Server 2008R2; Fetch two database name in cursor and then insert data to Table1 in two databases)

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DB  VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE CUR_DB CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT NAME FROM MASTER.SYS.DATABASES
        WHERE DATABASE_ID IN ('5', '81')
;

OPEN CUR_DB;
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO @DB.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, ''abc'', def'', 0)'
    EXEC(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB 
END;

CLOSE CUR_DB;
DEALLOCATE CUR_DB;
```

---

> Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: There is no db called `@DB`. Try `print @Sql` before executing.

Comment: When doing dynamic SQL like this, always make it a habit to comment out the EXEC(@SQL) statement, and replace it with a PRINT @SQL; statement. Then you can see the SQL you're producing, and easily spot any errors, or copy the output and paste into a query window and try to execute it to test if it's good.

Comment: @SqlZim, and pmbAustin, Thanks for your good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't concatenating the name of the database in your dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DB  VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE CUR_DB CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT NAME FROM MASTER.SYS.DATABASES
        WHERE DATABASE_ID IN ('5', '81')
;

OPEN CUR_DB;
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@DB) + '.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, ''abc'', def'', 0)'
    EXEC(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB 
END;

CLOSE CUR_DB;
DEALLOCATE CUR_DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a cursor for this? You have limited this to only two databases. Why not just code this as two insert statements and forget all the craziness with a cursor. This entire cursor structure is really this simple.

```
INSERT INTO DataBaseNameForDataBaseID5.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, 'abc', 'def', 0)
INSERT INTO DataBaseNameForDataBaseID81.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, 'abc', 'def', 0)
```

---EDIT---

Since you say you need to do this on more than those two databases you still don't need to resort to cursors for this kind of thing. Take a look at this. It utilizes dynamic sql but doesn't need a loop.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N''

select @SQL = @SQL + N'INSERT INTO ' + QuoteName(name) + N'.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, ''abc'', ''def'', 0);'
from sys.databases
where DATABASE_ID IN (5, 81) --No quotes here, these are integers, not strings

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: By the way, I am not sure "DataBaseNameForDataBaseID5" ? Do you mean: MASTER.SYS.DATABASESFORDatabaseID5 OR DatabasenameFORDatabaseID5? No space between FOR and database name? I mean the syntax issue.

Comment: that is just the name of the database. I don't know what they are because your original code only had the databaseid. :) It is just 3 part naming. [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] Does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below script

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DB  VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE CUR_DB CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM MASTER.SYS.DATABASES
    WHERE DATABASE_ID IN ('5', '81');

OPEN CUR_DB;
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ['+@DB+'].[dbo].[Table1] VALUES (100,''abc'',''def'', 0)'
    EXEC( @SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_DB INTO @DB 
END;

CLOSE CUR_DB;
DEALLOCATE CUR_DB;
```

There were 2 Issues in the script:

1. You were using the parameter name inside the Query string

   ```
   'INSERT INTO **@DB**.dbo.Table1 VALUES (100, ''abc'', def'', 0)'
   ```

this will cause an error because the EXEC statement runs all the statements given inside the brackets as a separate batch and none of the parameters that you declared before that comes outside the scope of the EXEC statement. So Instead change it as follow

```
     SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO **['+@DB+']**.[dbo].[Table1] VALUES (100, ''abc'', ''def'', 0)'
```

2. There were 2 single quotes missing before the before the value def

   ```
    VALUES (100, ''abc'', **def''**, 0)'
   ```

So I just added that.

Hope that helps.